# Question regarding infinite field lines

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, vector-fields, singularities

In the context of electric field lines, the following is an excerpt from [NCERT's *Physics Part 1: Textbook for Class XII*](https://ncert.nic.in/textbook/pdf/leph101.pdf)

> Another person may draw more lines. But the number of lines is not
> important. In fact, an infinite number of lines can be drawn in any region. It is the relative density of lines in different regions which is important.

I do not understand how this could be. Consider I have two regions $A$ and $B$ around an electric dipole. Say A is near the positive charge and $B$ is 50 m away from the dipole. I take a circle of area $1 \ \text{m}^2$ around $A$ and $B$.
I can draw infinite electric field lines in both $A$ and $B$, and find the relative "density" according to the textbook.
$$\text{field line density at A} = \frac{\infty}{1}$$
$$\text{field line density at B} = \frac{\infty}{1}$$
Since infinities cannot be compared how can we deduce that the field line density at $A$ is greater than at $B$ (which I know, in theory, should be correct)? I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the idea, consider the following which is easier to think about.

Suppose we have a layer of paint and we want to introduce a diagram to show the amount of paint per unit area. We could do this by showing dots on a plane. We can indicate the mass per unit area by the density of the dots. If near a point A there are 50 dots per square centimetre and near some other point B there are 5 dots per square centimetre, it means the density of the paint is ten times larger at A than at B. This is a useful kind of diagram, but it does not tell us what the density actually is unless there is some sort of key provided, to translate from "dots per unit area" to "mass of paint per unit area".

Indeed, another diagram could show exactly the same scenario but now with, say, 500 dots per square centimetre near A and 50 near B. It still shows the same factor 10 between the two places.

Electric field-line diagrams are like this. Now it is lines passing through a surface, rather than dots, but the idea is the same. One has to start with some arbitrary choice of how many lines per unit area will indicate one unit of electric field strength, and then the rest of the diagram allows one to compare field strengths (as well directions) at one place or another.

The mention of infinity in the book is just a way to say one can use any number of field lines at the outset, but it is indeed an unfortunate way of speaking because the one 'number' you cannot use is infinity, as you correctly point out! The book should have said "any finite number" and then it would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Setting something strictly equal to infinity so that everything is undefined and nothing can be calculated is not a useful thing to do in physics. Instead, consider the limit as the number of field lines *approaches* infinity. The ratio of field lines through plane A and field lines through plane B should remain constant as you *approach* infinity field lines going through either plane.

Answer (score 1):

Infitity is not a number and so you cannot do arithmetic with it.

*In fact, an infinite number of lines can be drawn in any region.*

is a short hand way of writing

*In fact, **as many lines, tens, hundreds, millions, billions, ets, as you want to draw** can be drawn in any region.*

Answer (score 1):

The prescription of drawing field lines is neither a mathematical nor a physical statement. Nothing in physics nor maths cares how people draw. It is merely a helpful convention that is aligned with intuitive ideas about strength to choose such a convention. Being mathematically pedantic here will only become self-harm.

Also, even if two quantities are infinities, does not mean that they equal to each other. $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{2x}x = 2$ i.e. You can draw double the amount of field/flux lines out of a charge that is doubly as strong of a charge as another, and still have infinitely many lines going through any one charge. In practice, you just decide arbirarily how many lines should be with a unit charge, and draw consistently for the others.